# Very simple ratio problem but got confused

Tags: percentages, ratio

If the men to women ratio is 1:1 and we have a total population of 21.7 mil and a literacy rate of 30/20 (% men to women)

how many more men than women are literate?

Is it 2,17 mil or 1,08 mil? Can't decide whether 30% and 20% is from the total of 21,7 mil or half (10,85 mil). 
   Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. How did you get each answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would take this to mean that $30\%$ of the men are literate and $20\%$ of the women are literate so the answer is $1.085$ million.
$$\frac{21700000}{2}=10850000$$
$$0.3*10850000=3255000$$
$$0.2*10850000=2170000$$
$$3255000-2170000=1085000$$
$\therefore difference = 1.085\enspace million$

Alternatively, we can get the answer in a much simpler way. Since there are the same number of men and women, the difference is just equal to $10\%$ of the number of men (or number of women). So we can just do:
$$0.1*10850000=1085000$$

Just bear in mind, your rounding is incorrect in the question. If you got the answer of $1.085$ then that rounds to $1.09$ to $2dp$ not $1.08$.